# c++ generic singly linked list string print fails

Tags: c++, string, generics, operator-overloading, header-files

I am implementing a generic singly linked list. It works with `char` and `int`, but not for `string`. What mistake have I made?  I get an error:

> C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
using namespace std; 

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data; 
    Node*next; 
    //friend class List<T>; 
}; 

template<typename T>
class List
{
public: 
    List() :headNode{ nullptr } {} // empty list constructor 

    ~List() // destructor
    {
        Node<T>*current = headNode; 
        while (current)
        {
            Node<T>*temp = current; 
            current = current->next; 
            delete temp; cout << "\nDeleting Nodes!!!";
        }
    }

    bool empty() const // is list empty?
    {
         return headNode == nullptr;
    }

    const T& front() const // get front element
    {
        return headNode->data;
    }

    void addFront(const T& e) // add to front of list
    {
        Node<T>* tempNode= new Node<T>; 
        tempNode->data = e; 
        tempNode->next = headNode; 
        headNode = tempNode;
    }

    void removeFront()
    {
        if (empty()) cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        else
        {
            Node<T> *tempNode = headNode;
            headNode = tempNode->next;
            delete tempNode; cout << "\nDeleting Node!!!";
        }
    }

    void printList()const
    {
        Node<T>*current = headNode; 
        while (current)
        {
            cout << current->data<<" |-> "; 
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

private: 
    Node<T> *headNode; 
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    List<int> mylist; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        mylist.addFront(rand()%200 + 20);
    }

    mylist.printList(); 
    mylist.removeFront(); cout << endl;
    mylist.printList();

    List<string>family; 
    family.addFront("aaa"); 
    family.addFront("bbb");
    family.addFront("ccc");
    family.addFront("ddd"); 
    family.printList();
    
    List<char> charlist; 
    charlist.addFront('a');
    charlist.addFront('b');
    charlist.addFront('c');
    charlist.addFront('d'); 
    charlist.printList();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You don't `#include <string>`. This is also one of the better linked lists I've seen a question about in the last few weeks. It otherwise works for me.

Comment: it worked for me:)) .thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are using "C **plus-plus,"** kindly save yourself a lot of time and simply use any one of several readily-available "container classes."  There's really no reason at all to "roll your own" linked list.

Comment: There is already STL list in library. But trying different implementation makes better at coding. thanks for your reply ...

Comment: The error message says you need to implement operator <<()

Comment: By the way i am new stackoverflow. i dont know how to post a question properly. I hope i ll better by time.

Comment: @dilem-ma-vi Include the header <string>

Comment: visual studio's compiler needs #include<string>. after adding string it worked. different compilers work differently. i think. thank for your time

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the header `<string>`.

```
#include <string>
```

where the `operator <<` for streams and the class `std::string` is declared.